# What´s the best way to service worker cached all files in AngularJs Application converted in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service-worker, browser-cache, progressive-web-apps

I want to caching all files of my PWA AngularJs project.

I using AngularJs 1.6.4, the service worker running without problem and my manifest.json it´s OK.

But my app only cache the default html files of the system.

```js
const CACHE_NAME = 'v1_cache',
  urlsToCache = [
    './**/*',    
    './css/main/*',
    './css/**/*',
    './fonts/**/*',
    './images/**/*',
    './img/**/*',
    './libs/**/*',
    './partials/**/*',
    './manifest.json',
    './sw.js'
  ]
```

In this case only cached the default html of the system, the manifest.json and sw.js

```js
const CACHE_NAME = 'v1_cache',
  urlsToCache = [
    './**/*',    
    './css/main/*',
    './css/**/*',
    './fonts/**/*',
    './images/**/*',
    './images/cabecera.png',
    './img/**/*',
    './libs/**/*',
    './partials/**/*',
    './partials/dashboard-partial.html',
    './manifest.json',
    './sw.js'
  ]
```

In the second case cached the default html of the system, the manifest.json,  sw.js, **`cabecera.png and partials/dashboard-partial.html`**

I need to especify each file I want to cached? or we've other option?

I need to cached every files of my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly specify each file you want to cache. There is no way to use wildcards from a client (page, service worker or web worker) to generate a request that returns a bulk set of responses. To cache an asset, the client must initiate a request for that specific asset.